# When creating a gensim vocabulary why did I get "decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, list found" error?

Tags: python, nltk, gensim, wikipedia, lda

I want to download a number of random Wikipedia articles (just the content) in order to introduce some randomness into the corpus and ultimately the topics. Then, I want to add the articles ‘Car’ and ‘Bus’ to the corpus.

```
import wikipedia

wikipedia_random_articles = wikipedia.random(5)
wikipedia_random_articles.append('Car')
wikipedia_random_articles.append('Bus')
```

This will return a list of seven article titles. These can then be downloaded:

wikipedia_articles = []
for wikipedia_article in wikipedia_random_articles:
wikipedia_articles.append([wikipedia_article, wikipedia.page(wikipedia_article).content])

Now, we have to clean, tokenize, and stem the articles. With the help of the NLTK:

```
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

def clean(article):
    title, document = article
    tokens = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+').tokenize(document.lower())
    tokens_clean = [token for token in tokens if token not in stopwords.words('english')]
    tokens_stemmed = [PorterStemmer().stem(token) for token in tokens_clean]
    return (title, tokens_stemmed)

wikipedia_articles_clean = list(map(clean, wikipedia_articles))
```

For the LDA model, we need a document-term matrix (a gensim dictionary) and all articles in vectorized format (we will be using a bag-of-words approach).

```
from gensim import corpora, models
import gensim

article_contents = [article[1] for article in wikipedia_articles_clean]
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(article_contents)
```

In order o constructing a vector representation of an article, I used following code:

bag_of_words = [dictionary.doc2bow(article_content)]

But I face with following error in Google Colab:

```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-28-aca107b9a54d> in <module>()
> ----> 1 bag_of_words = [dictionary.doc2bow(article_contents)]
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gensim/corpora/dictionary.py in
> doc2bow(self, document, allow_update, return_missing)
>     243         counter = defaultdict(int)
>     244         for w in document:
> --> 245             counter[w if isinstance(w, unicode) else unicode(w, 'utf-8')] += 1
>     246 
>     247         token2id = self.token2id
> 
> TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, list found
```

Would you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Presumably `w` is a list - have you tried any debugging like simply printing `w` immediately before that line?

Answer (score 0):

The expect input to `gensim.corpora.Dictionary` should be a list of list of string, e.g.

```
[
  ['clone', 'mammoth', 'scienc', 'extinct', 'fiction', 'book', 'biologist', 'beth', '...'], 
  ['saint', 'eutrop', 'former', 'commun', 'charent', 'depart', 'southwestern', 'franc', '...']
]
```

---

There's a simple_preprocess function that's pretty nice to use in `gensim`, https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html#gensim.utils.simple_preprocess

Using it as such should get you the `gensim.corpora.Dictionary` object:

```
import wikipedia

from gensim import corpora

from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess

documents = {title:simple_preprocess(wikipedia.page(title).content) for title in wikipedia.random(2)}

vocab = corpora.Dictionary(documents.values())
```

---

If you need to use more processing, with stemming and remove stopwords, you can try this:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer


stoplist = set(stopwords.words())
stemmer = PorterStemmer()

def preprocess(text):
    return [stemmer.stem(token) for token in simple_preprocess(text) if token not in stoplist]

documents = {title:preprocess(wikipedia.page(title).content) for title in wikipedia.random(2)}

vocab = corpora.Dictionary(documents.values())
```